# How to distinguish subrules in ANTLR 4?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have grammar with such rules:

```
type
 : '[' type ']'
 | '[' type ':' type ']'
 | type 'throws'? arrow_operator type
 | type 'rethrows' arrow_operator type
 | type_identifier
 | tuple_type
 | type '?'
 | type '!'
 | protocol_composition_type
 | type '.' 'Type'
 | type '.' 'Protocol'
 ;
```

I need to distinguish rules in my parser application. I know that I can label each alternative, but I don't want to modify grammar, because I use grammars-v4 repository for keeping grammar up-to-date.

Is there any other options that are easy to use? Or should I admit that I can't make my app without modifying the grammar?

Answer (score 0):

Certainly you can do it, but more tricky without alternative labels.
In visitor or listener method you can distinguish between them by the following way:

```
if (context.arrow_operator() != null)
{
    if (context.GetChild(1).GetText() == "rethrows")
    {
        // rule 4
    }
    else
    {
        // rule 3
    }
}
else if (context.type_identifier() != null)
{
    // rule 5
}
else
...
else if (context.type().Length == 2)
{
    // rule 2
}
else
{
    ...
}
```